# How to install a system windows 10 build on bootcamp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, big-sur

I need to install a special Windows build for the tasks I need. The build is on Windows 10 and there shouldn't be any problems... But there are.

When trying to give an image of Windows 10 to Bootcamp, bcamp says the image is not recognized.

Bootcamp works on BigSur. Is there a requirements guide or known issues with some install ISO processes?

Comment: Have you considered (and ruled out) a virtual machine (using VMware Fusion or Parallels) rather than bootcamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows 10 USB flash drive installer can be manually made using the following steps. Here, the assumption is Windows will be installed to UEFI boot.

1. Use the Disk Utility to erase the flash drive. Use table below to determine the proper choices.

   | Option | Value |
   | --- | --- |
   | Name: | Wininstall |
   | Format: | ExFAT |
   | Scheme: | Master Boot Record |
2. Mount the Windows ISO file and copy the contents to the flash drive.
3. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software. This should be done on the Mac where you are going to install Windows.
4. Copy the Windows Support Software to the flash drive. If you do this correctly, then the `BootCamp` directory will appear in the root directory of the flash drive.

When the Boot Camp Assistant is used to install Windows, some of the installation files can be produced by the Boot Camp Assistant. These files aid in the installation of Windows. Without these files, Windows can still be installed, but some aspects may need to be more manually configured.

Comment: bcamp does not allow you to use USB during an attempt to install Windows

Comment: If your [Mac has a T2 chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862), then you will have to [enable external boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198). After Windows is installed, you can disable external boot.